# Socket.io - server receives message but doesn't emit it to clients?

Tags: angular, socket.io

i have this server code:

```
 //socket IO
let socketIO = require('socket.io');
let io = socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    io.emit(message);
    console.log("socket message " + message);
  });
});
```

This is my client service:

```
  private socket;
  private url = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.socket = io(this.url);
  }

  createMessages(message: Message) {
    this.socket.emit('new-message', message.messages[0].messageText);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/messages/', message);
  }
  getMessage() {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on('new-message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    })
    return observable;
  }
```

And component code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
console.log(this.userService.currentUserValue);
this.messageService
.getMessage()
.subscribe((message: string) => {
  console.log('Message socket ' + message);
}, error => {
  console.log(error + " Error");
    });
  }
```

When i run it, my server outputs: User connected and  console.log("socket message " + message);. But my client doesn't get a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your server. You forgot to pass a parameter to specify the event name:

```js
socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    io.emit('new-message', message); // add 'new-message' as first parameter
    console.log("socket message " + message);
});
```